# How to create a kde(density plot) in a histogram which uses weight parameter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Originally, I have a bar data like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3.1, 3.2, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5, 6, 7])
y = np.random.rand(10)
s = pandas.Series(y, index=x)

1.0    0.895835
2.0    0.117966
3.1    0.397263
3.2    0.669877
4.1    0.330271
4.2    0.664608
4.3    0.006288
5.0    0.671697
6.0    0.587998
7.0    0.809034
dtype: float64
```

Then, I want to use this bar data create a histogram. So I add `weight=s.values` to achieve sum in a same section.

```
plt.hist(s.index, weights=s.values, bins=7)
plt.show(
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiBhL.png)

However I have no idea about how to bulit a kde in this figure.